# how to edit a user's information on WordPress Api

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, react-native

I'm using react native. I want to edit a user's information by a user id. so wordpress provides the api. when i'm using, getting error 401.

**Request failed with status code 401**

docs: https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#update-a-user

```
const userDate = {
      first_name: userDataAccount.firstName,
      last_name: userDataAccount.lastName,
};

const user = await WordpressApi.post("/wp-json/wp/v2/users/" + userFullInfo.id, userDate);
```

why is that? Please help me...

Comment: May be this error is coming due to authentication problem. Have you passed your consumer_key and consumer_secret in auth ?

Comment: yes, already passed. successfully fetched the user data by user id. when updating the user's info, getting an error 401. 

Do i want to pass any header or params?

Comment: Have you write permission from legacy api ?

Comment: i have fixed my problem. Thank you @KishanBharda. i added auth header in proper way even it didn't connected, getting error 401. but put http instead of https, it connects well. 

So that's ssl related problem, i need to double check wp ssl connection.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

i have fixed my problem. i added auth header in proper way even it didn't connected, getting error 401. but put http instead of https, it connects well. So that's ssl related problem, i need to double check wp ssl connection. Thank you